# $l^p$ not norm, $p<1$

Tags: functional-analysis

please I tried to find counterexamples to see that $l^p$ is not norm with $p<1$ in the triangle inequality but I have problems with convergence when I choose some successions. Thanks.

Comment: Let $p=1/2$ and $a,b>0$  Then $(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2=a+b+2\sqrt{ab}> a+b$. 

Let $x \in l^p$ be defined as $x_1=a$ and $x_i=0$ for $i\neq 1$, and 
let $y \in l^p$ be defined as $y_2=a$ and $y_i=0$ for $i\neq 2$.  Then we have 
$$\|x+y\|_p=(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b})^2 =a+b+2\sqrt{ab}> a+b = \|x\|_p+ \|y\|_p$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $p<1$. Then

$$\|(1,0,0,\ldots,0\ldots)\|_p=1$$

$$\|(0,1,0,\ldots,0\ldots)\|_p=1$$

$$\|(1,1,0,\ldots,0\ldots)\|_p=2^{1/p}>2$$

Answer (score 3):

The triangle inequality is violated for $v_1=(1,0,0,...)$ $v_2=(0,1,0,0,...)$.